# automation server can't create object on IE10

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-10

I have a web page from which i am creating activeX object and calling some methods in it.I have created msi file to register actveX dll. It works fine on my local machine but when i try it on other machines,it does not work. I have also installed the msi file on other machines and enabled "Initialize and script ActiveX Controls not marked as safe for scripting" in IE but still it does not work on other machines.
What is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check after you run the .msi that your ActiveX.dll is registered properly. You should see it in IE 10 under I believe "Tools" (gear icon) - "Manage Add-ons". It should be listed there, make sure you set the Show dropdown list to "All add-ons". If you don't see your ActiveX listed there, something went wrong with registering the ActiveX.

You'll want to troubleshoot your .msi at that point, run it with verbose logging turned on.

```
    msiexec /i MyActiveXInstaller.msi /l*vx "C:\Somepath\ErrorLog.log"
```